How to add custom claims to Access Token in client application registration and pass them to API
I have registered a Web API and a Client Application. The authentication works.
Now, if possible, I would like to achieve the following.
I want to register several Client Applications, each setting a different value for a custom "MyClaim" claim.
In the Web API code, I want to be able to read the "MyClaim" value from Access Token.

Please check the below answer and let me know if it works

To achieve your scenario, you can create token issuance start event in Azure Functions like below:
Create a function app, create an HTTPS trigger function and paste the below code for configuring claims:
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

    // Read the correlation ID from the Microsoft Entra request    
    string correlationId = data?.data.authenticationContext.correlationId;

    // Claims to return to Microsoft Entra
    ResponseContent r = new ResponseContent();
    r.data.actions[0].claims.CorrelationId = correlationId;
    r.data.actions[0].claims.MyClaim = "App1";
    r.data.actions[0].claims.DateOfBirth = "01/01/2000";
    r.data.actions[0].claims.CustomRoles.Add("Writer");
    r.data.actions[0].claims.CustomRoles.Add("Editor");
    return new OkObjectResult(r);
}
public class ResponseContent{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public ResponseContent()
    {
        data = new Data();
    }
}
public class Data{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.type")]
    public string odatatype { get; set; }
    public List<Action> actions { get; set; }
    public Data()
    {
        odatatype = "microsoft.graph.onTokenIssuanceStartResponseData";
        actions = new List<Action>();
        actions.Add(new Action());
    }
}
public class Action{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.type")]
    public string odatatype { get; set; }
    public Claims claims { get; set; }
    public Action()
    {
        odatatype = "microsoft.graph.tokenIssuanceStart.provideClaimsForToken";
        claims = new Claims();
    }
}
public class Claims{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string MyClaim { get; set; }
    public List<string> CustomRoles { get; set; }
    public Claims()
    {
        CustomRoles = new List<string>();
    }
}


And click on the Get Function URL -> Copy the default (Function key).
Create custom extension. Go to Enterprise applications -> Custom authentication extensions -> Create a custom extension

In ClientApp1, I granted API permissions like below:

In Manifest updated below values:
"acceptMappedClaims": true,
"requestedAccessTokenVersion": 2


Go to the Enterprise application -> Select ClientApp1-> Single sign-on -> Advanced settings - >Custom claims provider -> Congifure -> Select custom claim provider and SAVE:

And add a new claim:

For sample, I generated the access token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=ClientID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=api://xxxx/app.read&state=12345&nonce=12345

Claims are displayed successfully:


if possible, I would like to achieve the following. I want to register several Client Applications, each setting a different value for a custom "MyClaim" claim.

Yes, you can create Claims like below:
r.data.actions[0].claims.MyClaim1 = "App1";
r.data.actions[0].claims.MyClaim2 = "App2";
r.data.actions[0].claims.MyClaim3 = "App3";

And assign claims to the Enterprise application of each client app respectively and get them in token.
Reference:
Create a REST API for a token issuance event in Azure Functions - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft
